# How can I fetch data from specific offset in Kafka?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka-node client for publishing and subscribing from kafka. I want to fetch particular message of particular offset.

I don't know how it is possible. Please help if anyone have solution.

Thanks

Comment: you can use method `seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, but where can I find this method. I am using kafka-node client, there is no method like this.

Comment: there is a equal method `setOffset`

Comment: Not working,  I am sharing my code.
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient("127.0.0.1:9092"),
    consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
            { topic: 'TopicName1', partition: 0 }
        ],
        {
            autoCommit: false
        }
    );

console.log(consumer.setOffset('TopicName1', 0, 0))

Answer (score 2):

Of course, in general it's possible because the fetch request at low level Kafka protocol allows that specifying the starting offset.

Taking a look at the kafka-node library which I don't know much about, I see that the using the `addTopics` function you can pass topic information as well as the offset from which you want to start reading from and you need to set the `fromOffset` parameter to `true` as well.
There is the `setOffset` method as well for doing that.
Following the reference: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#consumer

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I just want to fetch single message using specific offset. If I use fromOffset  then it will consume from the given offset to the last offset, but I don't want like this. I have tried setOffset method but it is not working.

Comment: It's not possible then. You have to handle this at application level so getting more messages from that offset but processing only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a message broker for data stream processing and buffering, **it's not a database**. So **the random access to the data is not possible**. The limited reading strategy is to read data from a specific partition. At most, you can design your producer to distribute data according to your reading needs. For example, in receiving data from a sensor, someone can create a topic with 24 partitions and publish sensor data according to sampling timestamp. Now you have every hour data in a specific partition.

**However**, this strategy is not well-suited with the Kafka philosophy! In consuming data from Kafka you can reach the most data parallelism based on the number of partitions, **one consumer for each partition**. But when you publish every incoming message to partitions according to the sampling timestamp, just a partition at a time is buffering data and your application can consume data with parallelism one!